# Find out the deltaY distance?

Tags: javascript, delta

How do I find the distance from the touch center?

For example, we touch and if we pull up we get 1 2 3. If we pull down, we get -1 -2 -3.

I know it's possible to do it with a saved position (start touch). But I can't think about it myself. Thank you!

```js
// touchstart
window.addEventListener('touchmove', touchmove);

var deltaY;

function touchmove(e) {
  deltaY = e.touches[0].clientY;
  console.log(deltaY);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create 2 event listeners, one for capturing the start position, another for capturing the move events:

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', touchmove);
document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', touchstart);


var startX, startY;

function touchstart(e)
{
    startX = e.touches[0].clientX;
    startY = e.touches[0].clientY;
}

function touchmove(e)
{
  var deltaX = e.touches[0].clientX - startX,
        deltaY = e.touches[0].clientY - startY;


console.log('Delta x,y',deltaX, deltaY);
}
```